# Return Varchar from Custom T-SQL Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function

i would like to return a simple varchar value from a function that i define as follow :

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerType (@orderNumber INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
Return 
    (
    select custtype from Customer c 
        join order o on o.customerid =  c.customerid
    where o.orderNumber = @orderNumber 
 )
GO

select getCustType(1063609)
```

supposed to return customer type of customer who made order#1063609 but fails

Comment: You need to schema qualify the function call.

Comment: What do you mean ***fails***?

Comment: 'getCustType' is not a recognized function name. = FAILS

Comment: So use `dbo.getCustType` or whatever the correct schema is.

Comment: You need to put the name of the schema first, as @MartinSmith said. Something like `dbo.getCustType` or your custom schema

Comment: Please [read this](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx) and stop creating / referencing any objects without a schema prefix.

Comment: Why are you calling `getCustType` if the function was created as `getCustomerType`?

Comment: @AndriyM good catch. This is a good reason to follow a consistent naming scheme. If you can't even remember what you decided to name your own function, establish rules and a process.

Comment: Just a general comment, not trying to provide a solution, please relax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would alter the syntax of your function to the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getCustomerType (@orderNumber INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
begin
  declare @custtype varchar(30)
  SET @custtype = (select custtype 
                      from dbo.Customer c 
                      join dbo.[order] o 
                        on o.customerid =  c.customerid
                      where o.orderNumber = @orderNumber)

  return @custtype
end
```

Then when you call the function using the schema (`dbo.` below), you will use:

```
select dbo.getCustomerType(10636909)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dedb6/1)

The function can also be written as (thanks @MartinSmith):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getCustomerType (@orderNumber INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(30)
AS
begin
  return (select custtype 
                      from dbo.Customer c 
                      join dbo.[order] o 
                        on o.customerid =  c.customerid
                      where o.orderNumber = @orderNumber)
end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47ea3/1)

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `SELECTT @custtype = custtype FROM ....` instead? Would be even easier, me thinks...

Comment: @marc_s yes, I was just trying to be descriptive in my example.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the edit, I wrote it based on the sql fiddle...clearly I was not thinking.... :)

Comment: `return (select ...)` [is also fine](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cc1) without needing the intermediate variable but looks like `BEGIN ... END` are mandatory even for single statement scalar UDFs so the OP should have got another error that they didn't tell us.

Comment: I would add `select top 1 custtype` rather than just `select custtype`, the function in it's current state makes me nervous.

Comment: @MartinSmith you are right, I updated my answer to include that version as well.

Comment: @Martin yes `BEGIN/END` are required for scalar functions *until* we have *inline* scalar functions. [The reference to such a thing here is actually a bug in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, can this function go in as a field after the SELECT clause ? example : select x , y , dbo.getCustomerType(10636909) as z

Comment: @devved yes you can. Since the function is returning a scalar/single value -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46027/1